# Doubts on computing ETH daily number of active addresses

Tags: blockchain, addresses, code

I am trying to compute the number of daily active addresses from the ETH's blockchain. For this, I am using this mild SQL query:

```
SELECT
    date_trunc('day', block_timestamp) as day,
    COUNT(DISTINCT from_address) as active_addresses, 
    COUNT(from_address) as transactions
FROM
    "transactions"
WHERE
    date(block_timestamp) >= date('2023-02-01')
    AND block_timestamp < CURRENT_DATE
GROUP BY  1 
ORDER BY 1
```

When comparing with open websites charts (for instance bitcoincharts.com), the numbers don't match. Moreover, even in different sites and sources, there are discrepancies around 100.000 addresses.

My question is: there is something I am missing in the calculation? Am I possibly over count the addresses?

Answer (score 0):

you should add `to_address`.

e.g. include `COUNT(DISTINCT to_address) as active_addresses,` in your codes.

Also, besides `from`, and `to`, there is one more field: `contractCreated`, contract is also an address, so if you wanna include this also, then add transaction's `contractCreate` field in your codes.